# How to properly attribute Freebase

Tags: freebase

I hope this is the right place to ask this question.

I am attempting to attribute Freebase, but this website: https://www.freebase.com/policies/attribution

Does not produce any HTML code or image.

My question is: How do I give proper attribution to Freebase in a mobile app? Specifically, iOS.

Or, is the citation included in the API response sufficient?

Example:

```
citation =         {
            provider = Wikipedia;
            statement = "Description licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License).";
            uri = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgia_Institute_of_Technology";
        };
```

**EDIT:**

I've tried to access the website via Safari, Mozilla Firefox, and Google Chrome. All of which do not show any HTML code or image.

**EDIT 2:**

I've recently found this webpage, which seems to cover all types of licensing for Freebase. Although, I think some of the content is outdated.

http://legal.stefanomazzocchi.user.dev.freebaseapps.com/licensing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like they were the victim of their own API decommissioning.  If you look at the information returned by the Topic API, it includes attribution information for the given topic.  Basically what they want is:

- if you reference a single topic, your attribution should include a link to the equivalent Freebase topic
- if you link to multiple topics or derive general info from Freebase, you should link to the Freebase home page.
- if you're writing an academic paper, you cite the original Bollacker et al paper on Freebase.

Of course, not only am I not your lawyer or Google's lawyer, but I'm not a lawyer at all and this communication does not establish a client-lawyer relationship. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much Tom. Your answer is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way to attribute Freebase. If you can link to Freebase from some credits or help section of your app that would be sufficient. We'd also appreciate a mention of Freebase data in the app store but that's up to you.

Comment: I'll definitely mention in the description of my app that it uses Freebase data.