# How to attribute Freebase on my site

Tags: freebase

Since this page (https://www.freebase.com/policies) doesn't work and since credits data like wikipedia uri and statement, seems to be suddenly disappeared from topic queries (example: https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/017n9?filter=/common/topic/description), i would like to know how to credit freebase topics that contain text from wikipedia.

Is it enough to put links to freebase and wikipedia homepages with their respective licenses somewhere in my site or i must link every single topic to it's wikipedia page?

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.freebase.com/policies seems to work for me when I go to it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that page does not produce any html code below to "Here's the code:"

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct. Sorry about that. Check out this question: [how-to-properly-attribute-freebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115223/how-to-properly-attribute-freebase). It looks like the same issue.

Comment: Thanks, i've seen that topic, but it seems in contrast with what is written here https://www.freebase.com/policies : "Many Freebase descriptions come from the Wikipedia. Wikipedia content is licensed under the GFDL, which requires its own attribution." In addition, at the time it was written there was a wikipedia citation in the API response topic, now seems to have disappeared.